# React setState does not work simultaneously

Tags: reactjs

I made menuKey state to give each menu a key value.

so the return objects look like this:

```
                    <div className = "big-frame">
                        <div className = "big" 
                        onClick = {()=>this.onClick(1)} 
                        >111</div>

                        <div className = "big" 
                        onClick = {()=>this.onClick(2)} 
                        >222</div>

                        <div className = "big" 
                        onClick = {()=>this.onClick(3)} 
                        >333</div>
                    </div>
```

state and onClick look like this:

```
        state = {
            showSmall: false,
            showCont: false,
            MenuKey: null,
            contKey:null,
        }

        onClick = (k) => {
            this.setState({MenuKey: k})
        }
```

when I put console.log(k) and console.log(this.state.menuKey) in onClick
menuKey shows the previous value
for example it looks like this in console if I click 111, 222, 333:

1
null

2
1

3
2

what causes this and how to solve this?

Comment: What you have to fix it here? Updating the state is asynchronous process and so wont happen immediately. Put console.log inside the 
`useEffect` for tracking the updates ?

Comment: Refer this --> https://codesandbox.io/s/elated-drake-52v7w?file=/src/App.js

Comment: You know that setState is async, don't you?

Comment: your code looks good try to log in `componentDidUpdate` to trigger updates

Comment: I think I lacked knowledge at that time, was missing out componentDidUpdate // useEffect

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should change your code like this:

```
  componentDidUpdate() {
    console.log(this.state.MenuKey);
  }
  onClick = (k) => {
    const copy = { ...this.state };
    copy.MenuKey = k;
    this.setState({ copy });
  };
```